# If the caster of the Bane spell uses an action to increase the emanation's radius, does a creature that passes the saving throw have to repeat it?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

Jed the cleric is standing next to Gideon, his enemy. Jed casts [*bane*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=18); Gideon succeeds at his saving throw. On Jed's next turn, he uses the concentrate action to expand the aura and cause all creatures not yet "affected" to make a save. From the description of *bane*:

> Once per turn, starting the turn after you cast *bane*, you can use a single action, which has the concentrate trait, to increase the emanation's radius by 5 feet and force enemies in the area that weren't yet affected to attempt another saving throw. *Bane* can counteract *bless*.

Gideon already succeeded on the saving throw once. Does he have to make another saving throw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Gideon needs to save again.

> and force enemies in the area that weren't yet affected to attempt another saving throw.

If an enemy successfully saved, they weren't yet affected by *bane*, and the spell says you would force them to make another saving throw. Furthermroe, nothing in the *bane* spell grants foes succeeding their save temporary immunity to the spell... and the spell tells them to make another save. If it'd just said "a save" it'd be a little ambiguous, but the wording in *bane* is pretty clear that your concentration on the spell makes people retry their save.

Comment: A bit of additional support for this: a *lot* of effects in Pathfinder 2 indicate that saving gives you temporary immunity.  It wouldn't have required introducing anything strange to add it in, if they'd intended it to work like that.

Answer (score 4):

### Gideon only needs to Save once

From a writing perspective, there is *no point* to the text

> force enemies in the area that weren't yet affected to attempt another saving throw.

if it does not allow for creatures that have already Saved to ignore it. If they wanted to force re-Saves, they would more likely say that any creature that hadn't failed its Save, or similar phrasing. Unfortunately, the word 'affected' does cause questions and is not explicitly defined in the text. However, it is consistent elsewhere that when you Save against an ongoing effect, you have succeeded against the entire duration.

The only other text I see that tacitly confirms this is the rules on Bane's area, [Emanation](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=357).

> An emanation issues forth from each side of your space, extending out to a specified number of feet in all directions. For instance, the bless spell's emanation radiates 5 or more feet outward from the caster. Because the sides of a creature's space are the starting point for the emanation, an emanation from a Large or larger creature **affects** a greater overall area than that of a Medium or smaller creature. Unless the text states otherwise, the creature creating an emanation effect chooses whether the creature at its center is **affected**.

The area within the Emanation *is considered 'affected'* by this blurb.

Comment: but if they didn't have to make a first saving throw, then why would hey have to make _another_?

Comment: @BenBarden It is poorly worded, but I believe the saving throw is "another saving throw" compared to the initial casting whereas most spells either only have an initial save (or add that you can save at the end of each of your turns for some pseudo-incapacitates).

Answer (score 2):

### Gideon needs to save again.

Many spells that explicitly describe the outcomes of their (non-basic) saving throws, such as [tether](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=591) or [baleful polymorph](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=17) use the language "unaffected" to refer to a target suffering no effects as a result of their saving throw:

> **Critical Success** The target is unaffected.

While that does not in and of itself prove that *bane* is intended to use "affected" in the same way, it does establish that a creature can remain unaffected by a spell (or other effect that has targeted them) as a result of their saving throw.